# program/game design workflow

Tags: workflow, uml, standards

Programmer Types:

Do you write extensive design documents for your programs or games? 
Is using UML the standard method of diagramming your use cases? 
Do you run the whole gamut of diagrams or sort of pick and choose along the way depending on the scope of your software and the number of developers on the team?

Comment: This question may be better suited to [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/]

Answer (score 1):

First,

> If you make documentation, it should have a "clear" reason/purpose.
>   And this purpose is identify nature of your documentation.

Secondly:

> Do not think documentation just in a "written form" or word document.
>   It may be in any form.Even it can be  a "video" in which some guy
>   explain your major architecture decisons and why they choose
>   it[motivation]

Well, suppose that you want new team members "easily grab" what you are doing,how you are doing, and why you are doing this way.[ Be carefull all depends on your problem nature]

- UML use case diagram  may can give overall picture of your functional
  requirements. It simply states who will use your system, and what they can
  do with your system.
- Short memos which state the important non-functional requirements
- Short memos which states your major architecture decision and why you give this decisions
- Maybe a component diagrams which shows your important components and their interfaces
- If application tapology is important then may be a UML deployment diagram which shows how your system will be physically deployed.

But after all you can not document evething and you should not .You can generate whole system UML class diagram automatically with a UML tool, but how can this help a novice.

- But you can put class diagrams for classes that do important and tricky
  parts and draw sequence diagrams for those tricky parts which show how
  they collaborate with other classes while they perform important and
  tricky responsibilities.

> The key for documentaion is puting yourself into your "audience" [ who
>   will read your doc] and ask yourself
>
> - If I was this document potantial "audience" will i read this document? [ If not why you make doc]
> - If I read this doc, will it help me in some way? [ it is effective]

Lastly, we do not live in "ideal word"...Sometimes you may find yourself doing doc for no real audience and no real reason just because of some "politics" and you should earn money

Well, in this situation UML will help. Draw boring, with many details [ genarally auotumatically generated] diagrams which no one read or understand but say "Oh you have extensive documentaion". In our software industry, UML is overemphasized, and many guys "buy" even bad doc if there is a UML diagrams in it.

That's all folks...